# :last-child removes the body div

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I got a strange problem with jquery.
I have to remove the last child of the body to get the resize function work properly.
The last child is a div inserted by twitter-social-plugin and is obsolete.

In my resize-function I tried

```
$('body:last-child').remove();
```

The structure of the document is as follows

```
    <body>
        <div>here comes content and stuff</div>
        </div>that´s the div to be removed</div>
    </body>
```

When the resize-function is called, the whole body-tag is deleted and I get a blank page.
The resize-function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(window).bind('resize', function() {
                    $('body:last-child').remove();
                    contentStretch();
                    function contentStretch() {
                        $('#content-stretch').css({
                            height: "0"
                        });
                        var page_height =  $('#container').height();
                        var window_height = $(window).height();
                        var difference = window_height - page_height;
                        if (difference < 0) {
                            difference = 0;
                        };
                        $('#content-stretch').css({
                            height: difference + "px"
                        });
                    };
                });
            });
```

Comment: we cont give $("body:last-child").remove() because it is not compulsury that the last child of that body tag is div and need not the div that you want to delete

Answer (score 3):

The [`:last-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) gets the elements that are the last child of its parent, it doesn't look for the last child within the element. The `body` element is the last child of its parent, as there is only one `body` element.

To remove the last `div` that is an immediate child of the `body` element:

```
$('body > div:last-child').remove();
```

Comment: Guffa, you´ve made it :-) I only had to modify your line like $('body > div:last-child:not(#container)').remove(); due to the fact we got a bind-method running which would delete every last div on every pixel per resize-action. Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `:last-child` selector is a modifier for the item it is attached to. So you are essentially saying remove the last `body` element.

The simplest change that would make your code work to remove the last direct child of `body` would be to add a space to the selector.

`$('body :last-child').remove();`

However, that is somewhat dangerous and I would recommend being a bit more specific with exactly what you are removing. For example you could give all of the `div` elements a common class, such as `container`. Then you could also use the [:last-of-type](http://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/) selector. This ensures you will remove exactly what you expect, even if you have other elements of different types on the same level of your DOM structure.

`$('.container:last-of-type').remove();`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, Ruben

Comment: I got it to work as supposed to like $('body > div:last-child:not(#container)').remove(); The content remains that way on every pixel per resize.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('div:last').remove();
```

Comment: we cont give $("body:last-child").remove() because it is not compulsury that the last child of that body tag is div and need not the div that you want to delete

Comment: thanks gautam, that works fine but due to the bind on the resize, on every pixel the window is resized the last div will be removed till every div on the page is deleted and I have the same result as before. My try was to modify your line like $('div:last:not(#container)').remove(); but finally the #container will prepend and all of its content will be gone